# Same members in two base classes?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

Based on the UML below,`Scientist` and `Manager` classes are derived from `Student` and `Employee`. `Student` and `Employee` have the same public members, I'd ask which members would be taken (used) by `Scientist` and `Manager` classes?
[image]

Comment: Why don't you try this by your own? The practice is the best teacher.

Comment: @juergend - that's totally wrong. Multiple inheritance is very powerful thing (yes, error prone), but sometimes it's very useful. And no, it's not undefined.

Comment: @Adban: if you do use multiple inheritance, there is one simple rule: let only one base class have members and make other "interfaces" - i.e. classes with pure virtual methods only and without any member.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They would both have both. Each would have a `Employee::Name` and a `Student::Name`, for example.